# strip of words from a string in .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to keep the first 5 words from returned string, stripping of the balance.

eg. I want to keep "Stackoverflow is an amazing resources" from the word below

Stackoverflow is an amazing resources for developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) in combination with [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
Dim amazing = "Stackoverflow is amazing"
Dim notAmazing = amazing.Substring(0,  amazing.IndexOf(" is amazing"))
```

Or you could use [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Dim notAmazing = amazing.Remove(amazing.IndexOf(" is amazing"))
```

Or (as answered by paulius_i) [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx):

```
Dim notAmazing = amazing.Replace(" is amazing", String.Empty)
```

---

**Edit**: You've modified your question essentially, so here is a way to get the first n words of a string:

```
Dim amazing = "Stackoverflow is an amazing resources for developers"
Dim words = amazing.Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim first5Words = String.Join(" ", words.Take(5))
```

- [Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)
- [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Comment: The databse will be returning different strings. I changed my answer to make it clear. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly split the string into words:

```
var words = inputString.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Though you may need to use an overload to cater for other whitespace characters.

Next take the first 5 words:

```
var firstFive = words.Take(5)
```

This will return up to the first five words so it won't matter if there are less than 5 in the input string.

Finally recreate a sentence:

```
var output = string.Join(" ", firstFive)
```

Obviously you can combine these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a little fancier solution:

```cs
int remainingWords = 5;
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("Stackoverflow is an amazing resources for developers", "(.+? )|(.+?)", match =>
        {
        return remainingWords-- > 0 ? match.Value : "";
        });
```

Comment: Hmm... the string I gave is just an example. It will be returning different strings. Say I have a dataset of strings where I have different strings returned from the database. From those I need to keep only first 5 words. I should made it clear in the question.

Comment: Only now did I realize that it was tagged under vb.net. Sorry for C# code.